# $ is not Defined in external .JS file

Tags: jquery, html

I have 4 files for my page - html.html, css.css, javascript.js, and jquery.js. In my jquery.js file I am having issues as when I use the starting code it comes up with an error in the console. Here is the code:

```
$(function(){console.log("works")});
```

For some reason this comes up in the console log:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

Anyone know why and how to fix it? I think it may be related to the shorthand of the "document" thing and maybe because it is a separate file it doesn't work.

Comment: Is jQuery included before this file?

Comment: What does this mean? the entire file for my jquery.js is that. I only just started using separate files so Idk everything about it

Comment: Try reading this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194992/jquery-is-not-defined

Comment: @FinleySherwood You say you have `javascript.js` and `jquery.js`. One of them presumably contains jQuery, the other presumably contains your code that *uses* jQuery. Which one is included first?

Comment: Ok I found out why. The script source line for jquery.js was before the one for jquery. Thanks!

Comment: Put a min js pn the top of the all js [here](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery/) you can find the cdn

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQuery - $ is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194992/jquery-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you came across the solution so I'm going to still post this here for others to see:

It's highly likely you did not link the jQuery file first.

This would give the error you describe:

```
    <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
    <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js'></script>
```

This would be correct:

```
    <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
```

The reason why: your script.js uses jQuery. If you load the script.js first, jQuery specific delimiters, functions, etc will not be recognized in the script because they have not been defined yet.

Answer (score 1):

```
import $ from '../../assets/splitar/jquery-1.11.1.min.js';
```

Here you can replace your jquery store dir path and re run the project then your problem will sloved.